# Why does 1 / 2 == 0 using double?

Tags: java, double

I'm a high school student currently getting ready for a state academic meet(UIL). I have a problem and I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find an answer! Why does this print out 0.0?

```
double d = 1/2;
System.out.println(d);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's because of the data type.

When you do `1/2` that is integer division because two operands are integers, hence it resolves to zero (0.5 rounded down to zero).

If you convert any one of them to double, you'll get a double result.

```
double d = 1d/2;
```

or

```
double d = 1/2.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

1 and 2 are both integers, so `1 / 2 == 0`. The result doesn't get converted to `double` until it's assigned to the variable, but by then it's too late. If you want to do float division, do `1.0 / 2`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `1` and `2` are `int` values, so as per the java language spec, the result of an arithmetic operation on `int` operands is also `int`. Any non-whole number part of the result is discarded - ie the decimal part is truncated, `0.5` -> `0`

There is an automatic widening cast from `int` to `double` when the value is assigned to `d`, but cast is done on the `int` result, which is a whole number `0`.

If "fix" the problem, make one of the operands `double` by adding a "d" to the numeric literal:

```
double d = 1d/2;
System.out.println(d); // "0.5"
```

As per the language spec, when one of the operands of an arithmetic operation is `double`, the result is also `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Cause result of 1/2 = 0 and then result is parsing to double. You're using int instead of double. 
I think it should be ok:

```
double d = 1/2.0;
System.out.println(d);
```

Sorry for weak english